More elegant way to conditionally do several string replacements in Rust
I have a string that I need to perform some regex search/replaces on:
let signature = ...;

let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");

This works perfectly well and is nice and elegant and relatively efficient (in that it doesn't reallocate if there are no matches at least).
However I have a whole sequence of these replacements, and some of them I need to do conditionally:
let signature = ...;

if regex!(r"...").is_match(&logs) {
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
}

This obviously doesn't work because it's just making new signatures. This also doesn't work because of lifetime issues:
let signature = ...;

let signature = if regex!(r"...").is_match(&logs) {
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    let signature = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    signature
} else {
    signature
};

What you actually need to do is:
let signature = ...;

let signature0;
let signature1;
let signature2;

let signature = if regex!(r"...").is_match(&logs) {
    signature0 = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature, "...");
    signature1 = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature0, "...");
    signature2 = regex!(r"...").replace_all(&signature1, "...");
    signature2
} else {
    signature
};

However that's pretty awkward! Is there a more elegant way? Note, regex!() is
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! regex {
    ($re:literal $(,)?) => {{
        use {regex::Regex, std::sync::OnceLock};

        static RE: OnceLock<Regex> = OnceLock::new();
        RE.get_or_init(|| Regex::new($re).unwrap())
    }};
}

and the type of all the signatures is Cow<'_, str>.

I don't think there's any amazing solution, fundamentally the issue is that each replacement may return an owned string, and thus the next replacement must have a strict dependency on the previous replacement rather than the original, and thus every intermediate replacement has to be kept alive (because regex only takes references to haystacks). One option you could take at a slight efficiency hit is to check if any of the sub-replacement had to actually do something, and in that case return an owned signature otherwise return the original string.

You could even have the entire conditional replacement pipeline return an Option<String> for clarity, and the caller does the conversion back to cow and the fallback to te original signature in case of None.

@eggyal you can't use result outside the if because it borrows the local signature

Using this line from the docs of replace_all:

When a Cow::Borrowed is returned, the value returned is guaranteed to be equivalent to the haystack given.

You can make a function that updates the original signature without affecting the lifetime.
fn replace_all_in_place<R: Replacer>(regex: &Regex, s: &mut Cow<'_, str>, replacer: R) {
    let new = regex.replace_all(s, replacer);
    if let Cow::Owned(o) = new {
        *s = Cow::Owned(o);
    } // otherwise, no change was made
}

let logs = "r1";
let mut signature = Cow::Borrowed("r1r2r4");

if regex!(r"r1").is_match(&logs) {
    replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"r2"), &mut signature, "c2");
    replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"r3"), &mut signature, "c3");
    replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"r4"), &mut signature, "c4");
}


If you are looking for more performance, then there's a couple things you could do.
If your replacements can be made simultaneously (later replacements aren't affected by earlier replacements), then you could merge the regexes into one like in this example, except with a more complex Replacer.
If the above is true and your regexes are simple strings, then you can use aho-corasick for even more speed. See AhoCorasick::replace_all.

Ah very clever, thanks! My replacements don't depend on each other but there are quite a lot of them. Manually merging them into one mega-regex would be impractical. If there was a RegexSet::replace_all() I'd use that. Ah well, it's fast enough (this is replacing Python so I get a ~50x speed up just from that).

The easiest way is to write the replacement into a single persistent buffer. The buffer can be a Cow that only (re-)allocates if a replacement will be made.
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn replace_all_in_place(
    re: &regex::Regex,
    haystack: &mut Cow<'_, str>,
    mut replacement: impl regex::Replacer,
) {
    let mut caps = re.captures_iter(haystack).peekable();
    if caps.peek().is_none() {
        return;
    }

    let mut new = String::with_capacity(haystack.len());
    let mut last_match = 0;

    for caps in re.captures_iter(haystack) {
        let m = caps.get(0).unwrap();
        new.push_str(&haystack[last_match..m.start()]);
        replacement.replace_append(&caps, &mut new);
        last_match = m.end();
    }
    new.push_str(&haystack[last_match..]);
    *haystack = Cow::Owned(new);
}

fn main() {
    let mut signature = Cow::Borrowed("...");

    if regex!(r"...").is_match(".") {
        replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"..."), &mut signature, "...");
        replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"..."), &mut signature, "...");
        replace_all_in_place(regex!(r"..."), &mut signature, "...");
    }
}

